# asp.net mvc web api change parameter model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
public class UsernameBinder: System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);

        if (val != null)
        {
            //?????????????????????????????????????????
            //Get username property of user
            //Set username property = User.Identity.Name
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to create a model binder that binds username of user automatically. But I cauld not get property.

And I will use it like this:

```
public SendMessage CreateMessage([ModelBinder(typeof(UsernameBinder))]Message message)
{
}
```

How can I get property of a model from Web API?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api this should help you to bind the model of your action method to your `User`. Now to get the user in WebApi uses a slighty different convetion (for WebApi NOT WebApi 2)

Such as

`var username = ((ApiController)context.ControllerContext.Controller).User.Identity.Name;`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I really understood your question, but I solved a problem like this a shot time ago.

**Problem**: how to get the currentUserId in WebAPI controller actions?

```
// ex: update method 
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] MyModel model, Guid userId)
```

**Solution**:

Declare a binding and attribute:

```
public class CurrentUserIDParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    public CurrentUserIDParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
        : base(parameter)
    {
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
    HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Guid userId = /* my userid based on provider */;
        actionContext.ActionArguments[Descriptor.ParameterName] = userId;
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}

public class CurrentUserIDAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        return new CurrentUserIDParameterBinding(parameter);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] MyModel model, [CurrentUserID] Guid userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to add custom parameter binding rule?

like this:

```
config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, GetCustomParameterBinding);
```

see example [How to pass ObjectId from MongoDB in MVC.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143254/how-to-pass-objectid-from-mongodb-in-mvc-net/47107413#47107413)